# What happens if the barrier of a Cube of Force collide with an Passwall spell? And with a Wall of Fire for a 2nd time?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

I am creating an adventure that contains a *Cube of Force* and various spells mentioned in its description. I want to get the interactions clear so that I can design with them in mind.

The *Cube of Force* description says that, if the barrier *"is targeted by certain spells or comes into contact with certain spell or magic item effects"*, the item will lose additional charges.

The mechanics of instant effects are pretty clear: if a *Horn of Blasting* is activated and the thunder area overlaps with any part of the barrier, or if a *Disintegrate* spell targets the barrier, some charges are lost.  Non instant effects are not so clear:

- If a *Passwall* spell is cast targeting the barrier, 1d6 charges are lost, but does the *Passwall* create a hole in the barrier?  **Note:** as said in the accepted answer, a *Cube of Force* is not a valid target of a *Passwall* spell.
- If there is a preexisting *Passwall* affecting a wall, and the barrier collides with the hole created by the *Passwall*.  Does the spell cause the *Cube of Force* to lose charges and/or the barrier simply cover the hole while they overlap?
- If you make the barrier to collide with a Wall of Fire, 1d4 charges are lost.  If you take back and then forward, so you collide again with the **same** Wall of Fire, does the cube lose another d4 charges?.

Comment: Is this a real thing that happened, future-proofing, or idle curiosity? (I'm merely curious.)

Comment: Not happened ...yet.  I am creating an adventure that contains this object and spells.

Comment: Future-proofing then. That's cool. It might be worthwhile to include as part of the question the circumstances under which this confluence of events might occur. Sometimes questions that ask for answers to complicated mechanical interactions are closed because readers think the events will *never* happen, making them just code golf and off-topic. Maybe include in the question something like *In an upcoming adventure, the villain will have a* cube of force *and I expect the PCs to try to bypass the* cube *effect with a* passwall *spell* or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You will never have to worry about *passwall* targeting the barrier

[*Passwall's* description states](http://www.5esrd.com/spellcasting/all-spells/p/passwall) (emphasis mine):

> A passage appears at a point of your choice **that you can see on a wooden, plaster, or stone surface** (such as a wall, a ceiling, or a floor) within range, and lasts for the Duration.

The surface of the *Cube of Force* creates "a barrier of Invisible force". If the caster cannot see the barrier, typically requiring a spell like *See Invisibility*, then they cannot target the barrier. But even if they can see it, the barrier isn't wood, plaster, or stone. Thus, it is an invalid target for *Passwall* as far as a direct cast.

With that in mind, the only thing we need to worry about is the cube's barrier overlapping with an opening, created by *Passwall*, on a different surface. In that case, Passwall's effect has nothing to do with opening a passage in anything other than the surface it was originally cast on. Thus, we don't have to worry about any effect applying to the cube, aside from the specific description in the cube's text.

The cube loses 1d6 charges because the item's description says it does, but no hole is created in the barrier because the cube didn't say that would happen, and the *Passwall* spell wasn't cast on the barrier.

#### Repeatedly colliding with a *Wall of Fire* will continue to drain charges

The [cube's description](http://www.5esrd.com/gamemastering/magic-items/wondrous-items/#Cube_of_Force) only states:

> The cube loses charges when the barrier is targeted by certain spells or comes into contact with certain spell or magic item effects

The text makes no mention of "**The first time** the barrier is targeted..." in contrast to many other effects that do use this language. For example [*Wall of Fire*](http://www.5esrd.com/spellcasting/all-spells/w/wall-of-fire/) itself, which says:

> A creature takes the same damage when it enters the wall **for the first time on a turn or ends its turn there**.

From this, we can determine that no matter how many times you run into the same *Wall of Fire*, the cube will continually lose charges, because there is no exception which states that the drain was only meant to be applied one time.

Comment: I've been searching (not exhaustive!) and I haven't find any description that suggest a spell can be modeled in a diferent way that the **strickly** worded in its description (even the instant _Disintegrate_ spell specifically says that could target a _"creation of magical force"_).  Although a more flexible magic would be very nice, that does not seems the case of D&D 5e.  For all that reasons, I will accept this answer.

Comment: @techurbana based on Crawford's many tweets on the subject, RAW and RAI both point to all spell descriptions being interpreted with a strict definition (it only happens if it's stated) And conflicts are resolved by specific trumping general. The intent of WotC was to **always** follow the strict working of the spell.